# How to change the length of the unidentified speech signal during recognition?

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition

As described in several books, the process of recognition of isolated words consists of the following:

1. For a given set of signals(templates), determine feature vector for
   each template – matrix M×N, where M is number of
   features(MFCC,ZCR,…) and N is number of frames.
2. Train the templates with some algorithm, such as ANN, HMM, GMM, SVM.
3. Recognize test signal by trained model.

Because speech signals have different duration, their lengths are aligned by Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) technique, so that N is same for all templates. It can be done during training.

My question is: How to change length of test signal? I can not use DTW on it, since I do not know to which class it belongs. Should I use "time stretching" algorithms, preserving pitch and if I should, how this will affect recognition accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an equivalent MxN feature vector to one for a "time stretched" signal by extracting the features with the N frames spaced closer together or farther apart in time.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try. I suppose, the difference in window sizes for different signals doesn't matter, because human speech preserves its frequency properties on a time interval about 20-50 ms.

Comment: This would be suboptimal match compared with DTW because it assumes uniform stretch of the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the length to make a match. You extract features from reference samples and test samples, they all have different number of frames. Then you apply DTW between each reference and test thus aligning them. As a result of DTW runs you get the score of match between test sample and each of the references. What you do is you stretch non-uniformly each reference sample to match with test sample. Because you compared each reference with single test, you can use DTW scores in comparison. So you select the reference with best score as a result.

For details and ideas of DTW speech recognition check this [presentation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bhiksha/courses/11-756.asr/spring2013/lectures/class5.dtw.6feb2013.pdf).

If you want to get closer to ideas of speech recognition with DTW, you can read a book [Fundamentals of Speech Recognition 1st Edition
by Lawrence Rabiner, Biing-Hwang Juang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130151572).